# Resolving hierarchy of Win32_PnPEntities in WMI

Tags: c++, winapi, usb, wmi

I'm using a WMI query to receive events when USB devices are plugged or unplugged.

```
SELECT * FROM __InstanceOperationEvent WITHIN 1 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_USBControllerDevice'
```

From the received events I'm taking the `Dependent` object to get a Win32_PnPEntity.

The problem is, for pretty much any physical device, there are at least two logical devices.
So I'm receiving data such as:

```
Device unplugged: LPK25
Device unplugged: USB Composite Device
Device plugged: LPK25
instance of Win32_PnPEntity
{
        Caption = "LPK25";
        ClassGuid = "{4d36e96c-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}";
        CompatibleID = {"USB\\Class_01&SubClass_01&Prot_00", "USB\\Class_01&SubClass_01", "USB\\Class_01"};
        ConfigManagerErrorCode = 0;
        ConfigManagerUserConfig = FALSE;
        CreationClassName = "Win32_PnPEntity";
        Description = "USB Audio Device";
        DeviceID = "USB\\VID_09E8&PID_0076&MI_00\\6&383464A1&0&0000";
        HardwareID = {"USB\\VID_09E8&PID_0076&REV_0100&MI_00", "USB\\VID_09E8&PID_0076&MI_00"};
        Manufacturer = "(Generic USB Audio)";
        Name = "LPK25";
        PNPDeviceID = "USB\\VID_09E8&PID_0076&MI_00\\6&383464A1&0&0000";
        Service = "usbaudio";
        Status = "OK";
        SystemCreationClassName = "Win32_ComputerSystem";
        SystemName = "COMPUTER";
};

Device plugged: USB Composite Device
instance of Win32_PnPEntity
{
        Caption = "USB Composite Device";
        ClassGuid = "{36fc9e60-c465-11cf-8056-444553540000}";
        CompatibleID = {"USB\\DevClass_00&SubClass_00&Prot_00", "USB\\DevClass_00&SubClass_00", "USB\\DevClass_00", "USB\\COMPOSITE"};
        ConfigManagerErrorCode = 0;
        ConfigManagerUserConfig = FALSE;
        CreationClassName = "Win32_PnPEntity";
        Description = "USB Composite Device";
        DeviceID = "USB\\VID_09E8&PID_0076\\5&385A3465&0&2";
        HardwareID = {"USB\\VID_09E8&PID_0076&REV_0100", "USB\\VID_09E8&PID_0076"};
        Manufacturer = "(Standard USB Host Controller)";
        Name = "USB Composite Device";
        PNPDeviceID = "USB\\VID_09E8&PID_0076\\5&385A3465&0&2";
        Service = "usbccgp";
        Status = "OK";
        SystemCreationClassName = "Win32_ComputerSystem";
        SystemName = "COMPUTER";
};
```

Obviously, the LPK25 of these is the real device, while the USB Composite Device is some pseudo-entity.
For a mouse, I get four entities. For a game controller three, etc.
So how do I figure out which one of them is the "real thing?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my understanding you are making a confusion, for me it's normal you receive two events. It's because two new objects appears.

1. The low level object for you `usbccgp` is the low level driver for usb audio.
2. The high level object that support your audio hardware.

I think that you have to filter by service, for example I test with a USB key and I've got two events, one for `USBSTOR`(low level) and a second for `disk`(high level).

Comment: I know it's normal, but say that I was resolving the name of the device: the name of the device is LPK25, not USB Composite Device. If I open the Device Manager in windows, it won't show a USB Composite Device, only the LPK25.. I can link them together through DeviceID/HardwareID, but I'd want to be able to filter out the filter drivers and other crust that Windows lists as separate devices.